# What the right way to graph negative numbers in Protovis?

Tags: javascript, charts, protovis

For the simplest use case, a bar chart with values ranging from -10 to 10, how does one go about coding this cleanly using the Protovis JavaScript charting library?

By cleanly I mean centering the axis, showing x and y axis labels, and representing the column values of the chart where negative values fall below the y axis and positive values exceed the y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/yk5By/3/

The important parts of this are as follows:

- Make an x-axis scale going from your min value to your max value (in your case, it would be `pv.Scale.linear(-10,10).range(0,w)`; in my example, I calculate min and max based on the data).
- Base the width of the bar on the absolute distance of the datum from 0:

  ```
  .width(function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d) - x(0)); })
  ```
- Then adjust the `.left()` property based on whether the datum is positive or negative:

  ```
  .left(function(d) { return d > 0 ? x(0) : x(0) - this.width(); });
  ```
- Because we're using a simple x-axis scale, the adding axis labels is super-easy:

  ```
  vis.add(pv.Label)
      .data(x.ticks()) // you could also use pv.range(min, max, 1) here
      .left(x);
  ```

Comment: Much cleaner than what I was able to come up with. Nice. Complete answer. Thank you.